# How to set the small image in an FCM notification?

Tags: push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to set the small image displayed in the notifications.

[image]

I have added an iOS example. So the guy's face to the right is what I am looking to add.

[image]

Android seems to have a similar feature. So here is a woman's face to the left. The app is developed in Flutter and backend client is in java:

> compile group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-admin', version:
> '6.14.0'

```
MulticastMessage m = MulticastMessage.builder()
            .addToken(token)
            .setNotification(Notification.builder().setBody(body).setTitle(title).setImage(imageUrl).build())
            .build();
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendMulticast(m);
```

There is a feature to add an image, but that is rather large and appears below the message. How can the face images be added. Is it done on the app side or on the client side?

Comment: Got the same issue. Were you able to figure this out?